# Selenium JS Firefox window open and close immediately with no error

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, firefox

I'm just starting to discover Selenium with JS, using that tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BQ-9e13kJ58&list=PLZMWkkQEwOPl0udc9Dap2NbEAkwkdOTV3

I haven't figured out much yet about selenium and all, but I don't have any errors in my terminal and my code seems correct, but my firefox window only opens for 1sec and then closes immediately.

My code

```
const {Builder} = require ("selenium-webdriver")

async function example(){

    //launch the browser
    let driver = await new Builder().forBrowser("firefox").build();

    //navigate to our app location
    await driver.get("https://lambdatest.github.io/sample-todo-app/");

    //add a todo

    //close the browser

}
example()
```

I then follow the video indications and add "node tests/firstTest.js" in the terminal to lunch firefox (name of my files).

```
node tests/firstTest.js
Selenium Manager binary found at C:\Users\celia\Desktop\seleniumDemo\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\bin\windows\selenium-manager.exe
Driver path: C:\Users\celia\Desktop\seleniumGeko\geckodriver.exe
Browser path: C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe
```

Comment: There's not a lot of activity for node + selenium, you're probably better off switching to playwright